# Bounding sum of row norms of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be an $n\times k$ real matrix such that $A'A=I_k$. Then if $b_j$ denotes the $j$th column of $A$ we have $\sum_{j=1}^k || b_j || = k$ where $ || \cdot||$ denotes the Frobenius norm.

**Question:** Can I bound the sum of row norms:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n || a_i ||$$

where $a_i$ denotes the $i$th row of $A$? I feel like I should be able to bound it by $k$ as well, but somehow I can't show it.

Edit: In the comments user1551 provided a counterexample for the $k$ bound. Hence my question is what is the best bound I can put on this sum?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You have defined $a_j$ first as the $j$-th column of $A$. Then you redefine $a_i$ as the $i$-th row of $A$. Which definition is true?

Comment: @user1551 Sorry lets call $b_j$ the $j$th column of $A$.

Comment: @user1551 Yes of course, but can I bound this sum by something?

Comment: @user1551 Well $||b_j||=\sqrt{||b_j||^2}=\sqrt{1}=1$ if am not mistaken. Am  interested in $\sum_i\|a_i\|$, but not its exact value. I want a bound on it.

Comment: It isn't true that $\sum_i\|a_{i\ast}\|\le k$. E.g. let
$$
A=\frac12\pmatrix{1&1&1\\ 1&1&-1\\ 1&-1&1\\ 1&-1&-1}.
$$
It is straightforward to verify that $A^TA=I_3$, but $\sum_i\|a_{i\ast}\|=2\sqrt{3}>3$.

Comment: @user1551 Nice example! But then can I bound this sum by something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't true that $\sum_i\|a_{i\ast}\|\le k$. E.g. let
$$
A=\frac12\pmatrix{1&1&1\\ 1&1&-1\\ 1&-1&1\\ 1&-1&-1}.
$$
It is straightforward to verify that $A^TA=I_3$, but $\sum_i\|a_{i\ast}\|=2\sqrt{3}>3$.

However, as $\sum_i\|a_{i\ast}\|^2=\|A\|_F^2=\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)=k$, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\|a_{i\ast}\|\le\sqrt{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\|a_{i\ast}\|^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n1^2\right)}=\sqrt{kn}.
$$
Tie occurs when the norms of all rows of $A$ are the same, as shown by the above example.